# Switch from raw k8s manifests to helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

There are several applications in kubernetes cluster in our company. They are all written in raw k8s manifest style. By that I mean the following:

1. There are k8s manifests like deployment.yaml, service.yaml, etc.
2. The app was deployed using kubectl.

Now, we want to change these applications into helm charts, instead of raw k8s manifests. But there is a thing, I have never had any experience of such update. I mean, I have got our helm chart ready, but using `helm install` will cause a problem, cause I will have 2 same applications running in the cluster.

I have an idea of just deleting the old version and applying the helm chart, but it might cause a downtime which I do not want to happen.

Does anyone have an idea or experience of a smooth way of switching applications from raw k8s manifests to helm charts?

Comment: Did you try to follow [this article](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/adopting/from_kubernetes/) with some backup?

Comment: When we switched from pure k8s to helm, we deployed the application with a different name with helm and then switched the production traffic to the new application on our load balancer.